# How do I ask the assembler to "give me a full size register"?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm trying to allow the assembler to give me a register it chooses, and then use that register with inline assembly. I'm working with the program below, and its seg faulting. The program was compiled with `g++ -O1 -g2 -m64 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe`.

When I look at the crash under lldb, I believe I'm getting a 32-bit register rather than a 64-bit register. I'm trying to compute an address (base + offset) using `lea`, and store the result in a register the assembler chooses:

```
"lea (%0, %1), %2\n"
```

Above, I'm trying to say "use a register, and I'll refer to it as %2".

When I perform a disassembly, I see:

```
   0x100000b29:  leal   (%rbx,%rsi), %edi
-> 0x100000b2c:  movb   $0x0, (%edi)
```

So it appears the code being generated calculates and address using 64-bit values (rbx and rsi), but saves it to a 32-bit register (edi) (that the assembler chose).

Here are the values at the time of the crash:

```
(lldb) type format add --format hex register
(lldb) p $edi
(unsigned int) $3 = 1063330
(lldb) p $rbx
(unsigned long) $4 = 4296030616
(lldb) p $rsi
(unsigned long) $5 = 10
```

A quick note on the Input Operands below. If I drop the `"r" (2)`, then I get a compiler error when I refer to `%2` in the call to `lea`: `invalid operand number in inline asm string`.

How do I tell the assembler to "give me a full size register" and then refer to it in my program?

---

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string s("Hello world");
    cout << s << endl;

    char* ptr = &s[0];
    size_t size = s.length();

    if(ptr && size)
    {
        __asm__ __volatile__
        (
         "%=:\n"                /* generate a unique label for TOP */

         "subq $1, %1\n"        /* 0-based index */
         "lea (%0, %1), %2\n"   /* calcualte ptr[idx] */
         "movb $0, (%2)\n"      /* 0 -> ptr[size - 1] .. ptr[0] */
         "jnz %=b\n"            /* Back to TOP if non-zero */

         : /* no output */
         :  "r" (ptr), "r" (size), "r" (2)
         : "0", "1", "2", "cc"
         );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Sorry about these inline assembly questions. I hope this is the last one. I'm not really thrilled with using inline assembly in GCC because of pain points like this (and my fading memory). But its the only ***legal*** way I know to do what I want to do given GCC's interpretation of the qualifier `volatile` in C.

If interested, GCC interprets C's `volatile` qualifier as [hardware backed memory](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-03/msg00242.html), and anything else is an abuse and it results in an illegal program. So the following is ***not*** legal for GCC:

```
volatile void* g_tame_the_optimizer = NULL;
...

unsigned char* ptr = ...
size_t size = ...;

for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
   ptr[i] = 0x00;

g_tame_the_optimizer = ptr;
```

Interestingly, Microsoft uses a more customary interpretation of `volatile` (what most programmers expect - namely, anything can change the memory, and not just memory mapped hardware), and the code above is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc inline asm is a complicated beast. `"r" (2)` means allocate an `int` sized register and load it with the value `2`. If you just need an arbitrary scratch register you can declare a 64 bit early-clobber dummy output, such as `"=&r" (dummy)` in the output section, with `void *dummy` declared earlier. You can consult the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) for more details.

As to the final code snippet looks like you want a memory barrier, just as the linked email says. See the [manual for example](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html).

Comment: Thanks again @Jester. So I'm clear: there's no way to ask GCC to give me a full size register it chooses and then use it in my program? (If so, this  is second time I asked the wrong question. Its too bad Stack Overflow does not allow broad "How do I.." questions. Instead, I've got to go down a rabbit hole which results in multiple, poor questions).

Comment: My answer shows you how to do that in the first paragraph.

Comment: You can use a fixed register, but I am not aware of a way to let the compiler give you one without using my example. But you should really-really use memory barriers instead.

Comment: Thanks Jester. *"But you should really-really use memory barriers instead..."* - memory barriers don't solve the problem of dead code removal by the optimizer. That's the whole purpose of this exercise - "properly" stop the dead code removal. But I think you are right - to be most correct, a memory barrier is needed to ensure the writes complete before other access (release semantics).

Comment: Where is the dead code in your example? Nothing is removed from that.

Comment: There is no dead code in the first code example (top of the question) with the `__asm__ __volatile__` block. The second code example (bottom of the question) suffers it in the loop that writes `0x00` to `ptr[i]`. In the lower code, if the compiler can determine `string s` or `byte ptr[]` is not used, then the optimizer is free to remove the zeroization. The GCC folks tell me I'm to blame for the zeroizer being removed because I asked for optimizations (like `-O1`). I've already been down this road with them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68615/discussion-between-jester-and-jww).