# How to detect Android NDK toolchain?

Tags: android, android-ndk, c-preprocessor

I'm tuning some source files to use inline assembly in select places. One place is a rotate, where I'm seeing 4 to 6 instructions generated with the NDK tools. (Related, see [Near constant time rotate that does not violate the standards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31387778)).

When I try and use something like:

```c++
template<> inline word32 rotlFixed<word32>(word32 x, unsigned int y)
{
    assert(y < sizeof(word32));
    __asm__ ("ror %0, %1" : "+g" (x) : "I" ((unsigned char)(32-y)));
    return x;
}

template<> inline word32 rotrFixed<word32>(word32 x, unsigned int y)
{
    assert(y < sizeof(word32));
    __asm__ ("ror %0, %1" : "+g" (x) : "I" ((unsigned char)y));
    return x;
}
```

It results in:

```
$ make -f GNUmakefile-cross 
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 \
  -mthumb --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm \
  -I/opt/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/ -c 3way.cpp
.../ccwZw2eI.s: Assembler messages:
.../ccwZw2eI.s:2123: Error: ror #imm not supported -- `ror r0,#16'
.../ccwZw2eI.s:2133: Error: ror #imm not supported -- `ror r3,#24'
.../ccwZw2eI.s:2847: Error: ror #imm not supported -- `ror r6,#10'
...
```

So the compiler does not support an immediate-8 version of a rotate. Its not  big loss since there are so many registers available (relatively speaking). But I'd like to be able to identify the situation because `rotlFixed` and `rotrFixed` are supposed to use the immediate version of the instruction.

Now, looking for something to key on to identify the situation:

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-cpp -dM < /dev/null | grep -i android
#define __ANDROID__ 1
$ arm-linux-androideabi-cpp -dM < /dev/null | grep -i aosp
$ arm-linux-androideabi-cpp -dM < /dev/null | grep -i ndk
$
```

It appears the NDK toolchain only provides `__ANDROID__`. I believe other native mobile toolchains define it too, so I can't use it. And there's no `__ANDROID_CC__` or similar.

How can I detect the Android NDK toolchain?

Answer (score 0):

`__ANDROID_NDK__` should only be defined by the NDK toolchains.