# C how to roll bytes

Tags: c, byte, bit-shift

This is just something I wanted to do for fun, no real practical use of it.

Say for example I enter 0xDEADAAAA

I want to be able to transform the value into 0xDDEAAAAA

Meaning the 4 most significant bytes shift over one byte.
And the 4th most significant byte now becomes the first most significant byte.

Kind of like a circular shift of the first 4 bytes.

For now I'm doing

```
value = value >> ((sizeof(unsigned int) * 8) / 2);
```

This will shift all bytes over one byte. 
But how would I do the circular roll of the 4th most significant byte into the MSB?

Comment: A string has no "most significant byte". And if that is supposed to be an integer: it seem to only have 4 bytes. It is not clear what you mean. See [ask], provide a [mcve]. And search for "c operators", if that is not too much asked.

Comment: See [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).  You need to rotate 4 high-order bytes while leaving the low-ones unchanged (though with the value AAAA in the low-order bytes, it will be hard to spot mishandled changes that preserve byte values; use `0xDEAD0123` or something else with distinct bytes in the low-order part of the value.  Also, you seem to be mixing up bytes with nybbles; each hex digit is a nybble (aka nibble), and it appears you want to deal with the 4 most significant nybbles, not bytes.

Comment: It's an unsigned integer not a string.  I'm just representing it in hexadecimal for readability.

Comment: Ah you're right yes nibbles not bytes then. Because a nibble is 4 binary digits correct? And a byte is 8?

Comment: Yes; a nybble is 4 bits and a byte is 8 bits on most systems these days.  (The exceptions are few and far between and I've never programmed on any of them.)

Comment: See also [Best practices for circular shift rotate operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c) and [Near constant time rotate that doesn't violate the standards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387778/near-constant-time-rotate-that-does-not-violate-the-standards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the number into three parts and process them separately, then combine them.

The part that is unchanged is `value & 0x0000FFFF`.
The part that you want to shift right 4 bits is `value & 0xFFF00000`.
The part that you want to shift left 12 bits is `value & 0x000F0000`.

So do all of those things, then combine the results with `|`:

```
value =  (value & 0x0000FFFF)
      | ((value & 0x000F0000) << 12)
      | ((value & 0xFFF00000) >> 4);
```

(note, here I've lined up all the masks so it's easy to see, but obviously you don't have to do that)