# C rotl32 alternative

Tags: c, opencl

is there an alternative for `rotl32` in C language?

i found this: [Near constant time rotate that does not violate the standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387778/near-constant-time-rotate-that-does-not-violate-the-standards/31488147#31488147)
but still trying to get an optimized one

my code:

```
k0 = rotl32 ((k3 ^ k2 ^ k ^ k0), 1u)
```

Comment: opencl has rotate function https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/rotate.html

Comment: What's wrong with the answer you've already found? "...trying to get an optimized one" suggests it's not optimal, but how so?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best portable option:

```
uint32_t rotl32(uint32_t var, uint32_t hops)
{
    return (var << hops) | (var >> (32 - hops));
}
```

Comment: This does not work for `hops == 0`.  Fix it without a test: `return (var << hops) | (var >> ((32 - hops) & 31));`

Comment: What would make this fail? We're shifting right out of bounds, and the shifting feeds 0's in from the left. Works fine in gcc 4.8.5?

Comment: If `hops == 0`, `var >> (32 - hops)` has undefined behavior. On x86 processors, it would compute `var >> 0` but on others it might compute something else, such as `var >> 32` which could evaluate to 0, which is OK too, but the C Standard does not guarantee that these are the only possible behaviors (unfortunately). In fact anything is possible, so this corner case must be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You have opencl tag in your question, so with a kernel

```
__kernel void rotateGpu(__global unsigned int * a,__global unsigned int * b)
{
  int idx = get_global_id(0);
  unsigned int a0=a[idx];
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        a0=rotate(a0,1280u);
  b[idx] = rotate(a0,1280u);

}
```

`rotate` performance on R7-240 GPU according to a benchmark:

32 million element-array of 32b unsigned integers such as `a0`, kernel execution takes 16ms where each thread does 100 times(10 ms for 1 times) rotation of 1280u step length(so latency is independent of step length)) . Its more than 200 Gflops(but on integers) reaching %40 theoretical maximum of gpu . Maybe its even faster for integers than floats(they would need normalization after shift I suppose).

Example:

```
__kernel void rotateGpu(__global unsigned int * a,__global unsigned int * b)
{
  int idx = get_global_id(0);
  unsigned int a0=a[idx];

  b[idx] = rotate(a0,2u);

}
```

input:

```
        buf[0] = 80;
        buf[1] = 12;
        buf[2] = 14;
        buf[3] = 5 ;
        buf[4] = 70;
```

output:

```
320 
48 
56 
20 
280
```

Comment: does it perform faster than the opencl rotate function?

Comment: But what I wrote here is opencl rotate function, just tested it. Maybe its the compiler's ability to optimize it. Maybe nvidia has different time complexity or latency

Comment: can you include an usage example?

Comment: added an example that rotates left by 2 step length

Comment: i didn't get it,, can you please make it simple as my code above ?

Comment: `k0 = rotate((k3 ^ k2 ^ k ^ k0), 1u)` so looks very similar. you want it for opencl (>= 1.0)right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135468/discussion-between-abdelhafidh-belalia-and-huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik).

Answer (score 0):

dromtrund posted a good portable solution:

```
uint32_t rotl32(uint32_t var, uint32_t hops) {
    return (var << hops) | (var >> (32 - hops));
}
```

Unfortunately, this function has undefined behavior for `hops == 0`.  On the x86 processors, only the low order bits of `hops` are significant. This behavior can be forced this way:

```
uint32_t rotl32(uint32_t var, uint32_t hops) {
    return (var << hops) | (var >> ((32 - hops) & 31));
}
```

Both functions compile to optimal code with gcc 4.9 and up, clang 3.5 and up and icc 17, as can be verified with [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/LS21kF).

John Regehr has an [interesting blog article](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1063) on this very subject.